# Wait until coroutine finishes before starting another coroutine [Unity C#]

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coroutine, ienumerator

I'm a bit of a beginner and my knowledge of coroutines is incredibly limited.
I have Coroutine1 generating two Lists and Coroutine2 that would use those two lists. When doing this:

```
void test ()
{   
    StartCoroutine (Coroutine1);
    StartCoroutine (Coroutine2);
}
```

only one of the Lists is generated resulting in an error inside Coroutine2.
But if I do this:

```
IEnumerator Coroutine1(){
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfListsToBeGenerated; i++) {
        //generate List
        yield return StartCoroutine(Coroutine2());
    }
}
```

Unity freezes up. I'm using coroutines to solve optimization issues as generating the lists would cause a freeze.

Comment: Can / Are the lists be / being used as a class property?

Comment: The two lists generated in Coroutine1 are properties of Object1 and Object2 of type Class1. Coroutine2 is to generate List3 from Object1.List and Object2.List and use that as a property of Object3 of type Class2.

Comment: did you try puting a `yield return new WaitForEndofFrame`

Comment: waitForEndOfFrame does not help, nothing changed

Answer (score 4):

If you want to wait for one coroutine till it finishes, you can put `yield return Coroutine1();` at first line in the body `Coroutine2` and put the rest of the code after that, this way the `Coroutine2` will wait for `Coroutine1` till its done, then it will proceed with the rest of the code.

```
void Start() {
    StartCoroutine(Coroutine2());
}

IEnumerator Coroutine2() {
    yield return Coroutine1();

    //Coroutine1 is now finished and you can use its result
}
IEnumerator Coroutine1() {
    //create your lists then call yield return
    yield return null;
}
```

Comment: Sadly that crashes Unity too

Comment: @IGClusterFck See the edit I just made, there was a minor syntax error in the answer that I corrected. I also tested it and it works fine. Do note that you do not need to `yield return null` when the coroutine is complete, it can be left off. You would still want a `yield` somewhere else, if necessarily (e.g. `yield return WWW`).